# JQuery - plot time series data from php using Flot Charts

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, flot

I get data from database which is formatted using php and returned as JSON response for an Ajax call. Every thing works fine and data is plotted. But if X-Axis contains date then nothing is plotted. I submit a starting and an end date using Ajax. Here is the data, I generate as response:

```
[
  {
    "data": [
      [
        "2014-11-02",
        5
      ],
      [
        "2014-11-04",
        12
      ],
      [
        "2014-11-07",
        2
      ],
      [
        "2014-11-13",
        21
      ]
    ],
    "label": "Label1",
    "color": 8
  }
]
```

My x-Axis:

```
xaxes : [ {
            mode : "time",
            timeformat : "%y-%m-%d",
            color : "black",
            axisLabel : "Date",
            axisLabelUseCanvas : true,
            axisLabelFontSizePixels : 12,
            axisLabelFontFamily : 'Verdana, Arial',
            axisLabelPadding : 10
        }],
```

I followed the tutorial : http://www.jqueryflottutorial.com/how-to-make-jquery-flot-time-series-chart.html
but cannot figure out how to do it with when using data from ajax response.

Also, how can I divide the ticks according to start and end dates automatically?

Comment: Show your `$.plot(/* your code */)`

Comment: @user1477388 added my x-axis code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date in the JSON needed to be a Date object which flot expects in time mode. So following worked for me: (converting string date to Date object before passing to flot):

```
var graph_json = $.parseJSON(data);

var j, i;
for(j=0;j<graph_json.length;j++){
    for(i=0;i<graph_json[j].data.length;i++){
        graph_json[j].data[i][0] = new Date(graph_json[j].data[i][0]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See my comment above.  First glance, looks like you need to add this property to your `xaxis` object:

```
timeformat:"%y/%m/%d"
```